# Swing RTF editing component - alternatives to RTFEditorkit?

Tags: java, swing, rtf, rich-text-editor

I want to embed an RTF editing swing component into an application. There is JTextPane which can be used with RTFEditorkit, and I have created a small sample editor with it. But there are issues, and from what I find on the web, it looks like development of RTFEditorkit is stagnating.

Does anyone know about alternatives?

PS: I know I could embed OpenOffice.org (or LibreOffice), but requiring installation of a complete office suite just for editing RTF files is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this attempt to replace SUN's RTFEditorKit
http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html

Comment: @Axel Did you manage to get the Advanced RTFEditorKit to work?